# How to proof the linear independency of the random vectors with this specific structure?

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

I have this stupid problem with $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^m$ for $i=1,\ldots,2m$ with independent and identically random entries of some continuous distribution, and the set of vectors

$$S_m:=\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}\sum_{i=1}^{2m} a_i\\\sum_{i=1}^{2m} a_i\end{matrix}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^{2m}\right\}\cup\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}a_1-a_2\\a_{2m}-a_1\end{matrix}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^{2m}\right\}\cup\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}a_i-a_{i+1}\\a_{i-1}-a_i\end{matrix}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^{2m}\;\middle|\;i=2,\ldots,2m-1\right\}$$
I would like to proof, that the $2m$ vectors in the set $S_m$ are linearly independent with high probability for all $m$. How?

The set looks a little complicated, but it's not at all. Here a small example for easier understanding of the structure:

**Example $m=2$:**
$$S_2=\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\\a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}a_1-a_2\\a_4-a_1\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}a_2-a_3\\a_1-a_2\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}a_3-a_4\\a_2-a_3\end{matrix}\right]\right\}$$
Why are those vectors linearly independent with high probability?

**EDIT**

As I just noticed through substituting the coefficients of the equation system with all vectors in $S_m$ set to $0$, this is the same as asking how to proof that the vectors from the set $$T_m:=\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}a_1\\a_{2m}\end{matrix}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^{2m}\right\}\cup\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}a_i\\a_{i-1}\end{matrix}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^{2m}\;\middle|\;i=2,\ldots,2m\right\}$$
or, respectively, for the example
$$T_2=\left\{\left[\begin{matrix}a_1\\a_4\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}a_2\\a_1\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}a_3\\a_2\end{matrix}\right],\left[\begin{matrix}a_4\\a_3\end{matrix}\right]\right\}$$
are linearly independent with high probability. Any ideas? Or can I assume this? Is it obvious?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the rank of $S_m$, in random coordinates $\{a_i\}$ that are i.i.d. . In your $m=2$ example, the associated matrix to check is:
$$    \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &1 &1 &1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}  $$
Notice the structure of the matrix, and how it'll grow as $m$ increases. Then proceed by induction.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really see the connection of checking the rank of this matrix to my case. I see the rule and understand how you created is, but why is it's rank the number of linearly independent vectors in $S_m$. Please explain.